# Clean _GET var string in PHP to only letters

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I have the common used function php get to include a file and display it as a page like this

```
index.php?F=contact
<?php
$file=$_GET['F'];
include('the_files/'.$file.'.php');
?>
This will display file contact.php
```

Because of security I want to filter the

```
$file=$_GET['F'];
```

with some kind of code so only text without simbols without slashes will get in the INCLUDE

I tried with

```
 <?php
    $clean_file=mysqli_real_escape_string($clean_file,$_GET['F']);
    include('the_files/'.$clean.'.php');
    ?>
```

But it seems like this is only to clean MySQLi...

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Where do the files come from?

Comment: The files comes from the same server

Comment: Use a white list or switch-case or what ever. Only include files if you know that they exist. Don't believe to be smarter than anyone who tries to compromise your site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$file = preg_replace('/[^a-z_\-]/i', '', $_GET['F']);
```

Of course, I would just run a test and send them to IC3, if they're trying to hack your page.

Comment: what does the /i means in this preg replace ?

Comment: That's `insensitive`.

Comment: Last question: The slashes ///// are disabled with this code too right?

Comment: Nice solution PHPglue

Comment: The expression replaces any character that is not `a` through `z` and `_` and `-`, so it will replace slashes too.

Answer (score 0):

You're right it's really tricky to allow the user to control which script gets executed.  I would go further than just sanitizing the input. Instead, I would analyze the full path and make sure it's within the allowed directory.

```
// path to include files, relative to the document root
const INCLUDE_DIR = '/the_files/';

$file = $_GET['F'];

// resolve the real path (after resolving ../ and ./)
$fileFullPath = realpath(INCLUDE_DIR . $file);

// if file doesn't exist
if($fileFullPath === false ||
    // or the file is not in INCLUDE_DIR
    str_replace($file,'',$fileFullPath) != $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . INCLUDE_DIR
): 
    http_response_code(404); // 404 Not Found error
    exit;
endif;

// here we know that the file exists and is in INCLUDE_DIR
include $fileFullPath;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

Make a Whitelist like this and check if the Parameter-Value is in the Whitelist or not.

```
$whitelist = array('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc');

if(in_array($_GET['page'], $whitelist)){
 include($_GET['page'].'.php');
}else{
 include('default.php');
}
```

Or check, if the File exists, if all possible Values are Filenames

```
$file = preg_replace('/[^a-z]/', '', $_GET['page']).'.php'; // remove all non-a-z-Characters

if(file_exists($file)){
 include($file);
}else{
 include('default.php');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Use this function

$file = mysql_prep($_GET['f']);

function mysql_prep( $value ) {
        $magic_quotes_active = get_magic_quotes_gpc();
        $new_enough_php = function_exists( "mysql_real_escape_string" ); // i.e. PHP >= v4.3.0
        if( $new_enough_php ) { // PHP v4.3.0 or higher
            // undo any magic quote effects so mysql_real_escape_string can do the work
            if( $magic_quotes_active ) { $value = stripslashes( $value ); }
            $value = mysql_real_escape_string( $value );
        } else { // before PHP v4.3.0
            // if magic quotes aren't already on then add slashes manually
            if( !$magic_quotes_active ) { $value = addslashes( $value ); }
            // if magic quotes are active, then the slashes already exist
        }
        return $value;
    }
```